# C# download file stealthy?

Tags: c#, security, download

I was wondering how I would go about retrieving a file in a way that wouldn't be shown (or at least somewhat encrypted) in a web debugger or similar tool (wireshark for instance). 
 
I am currently using FTP, but FTP has a couple security flaws such as username and password being viewable in a web debugger or in programs that have been created for getting FTP username and password. Would SFTP be any safer?

Comment: If you want the file to be encrypted, encrypting is it indeed a good way to achieve that. "Ok Google, what is the difference between FTP and SFTP".

Comment: Use FTPS or SFTP

Comment: Explaining the difference between different network protocols is outside of the scope of [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to remember here is that Wireshark/Fiddler/et al see *every packet* that moves through your card. If you have a legitimate need to hide traffic from the card (and I don't see how you could), you're looking at some drastic measures.

With that in mind, establishing a VPN link is likely your best bet. That makes all traffic through your card look pretty much the same, even the legitimate stuff. A simple HTTPS connection might help, too, but in this case you still leak that *something* was being downloaded, as well as the base domain name (not full URL). Failing that... don't use the card. Fall back to a serial connection or USB thumb drive.